# SharePoint workflow 2010 assigned task is still pointing to internal URL

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

We have SharePoint 2010 intranet that is exposed to external url:

```
internal url: http://domain:4000
external url: http://testdomain.com.au
```

We have setup alternative access mapping which to exposed internal url to external url.

We use the out of the box approval workflow for our list. The problem that I am having right now is when the user received task assigned to them. When they try to go VIew Task, the link is still pointing to internal url.

Please advise how I can resolve this issue, where the task url is point to the external url.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason you locked into using the out of the box workflows? Seems like this could be easily rectified with a customized workflow in SPDesigner.

EDIT: Since you state it has to be and out of the box workflow I would say you won't be able to achieve the change you are looking for. Modifying OOB workflows in SP2010 is a very complex task, I don't know anyone who has done it successfully and likely isn't supported by Microsoft.

I do know you can associate OOB workflows to other lists, MS doesn't have an easy way to crack that workflow open and change the code on it.

However, if you were to use SharePoint Designer - you could create a notification workflow and set the hyperlink to whatever you wanted. Micosoft has an [excellent primer here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/workflow-actions-in-sharepoint-designer-2010-a-quick-reference-guide-HA010376961.aspx)

Comment: This answer is more suited as a question on the post, unless you do extend it with some information regarding your proposed solution :)

Comment: Yes. it needs to used out of the box workflow.