# SharePoint 2013 task url issue

Tags: 2013, workflow, visual-studio-2012, workflow-activity

[Possible Duplicate](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/81049/sharepoint-workflow-2010-assigned-task-is-still-pointing-to-internal-url)

I am working on SharePoint 2013 visual studio workflow, while creating the single task activity email body, I am using

> '%TaskSpecial: TaskUrl%'

token

```
<a href='%TaskSpecial: TaskUrl%'>my Task</a>
```

but the token is pointing to the internal URL, while the environment is mapped to a external URL.

Are there any other special token that I am missing or I have to generate the url?

Comment: Read in the following blog that I need to set the mapped URL as the default zone URL in central admin AAM, Tried the same but still it is pointing to the internal URL.https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f435764f-62c3-474f-95cb-77203a1f1eac/workflow-sent-email-with-default-zone-url-in-sharepoint-i-need-to-send-it-with-intranet-zone-url?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change the AAM to have the external url as the DEFAULT. Next, re-register the workflow service via PowerShell. Finally, Reactivate the workflow feature(s).